# SQL Search Query with substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to convert some searching C# code over to an old SQL project but I don't know how to:

1. split strings in SQL
2. perform a "WHERE LIKE IN (@subTerms)"

Edit: I'm using MS SQL Server 2012.

Sorry I thought my question had enough information, the corresponding SQL table would look like:

**TableName**: Products

**Columns**: ID (int), Name (varchar)

**Data**:

MyProduct

My Stuff

Super Product

My SQL would look something like:

```
DECLARE @term varchar;
SET @term = "My Product"

DECLARE @subTerms varchar/array;
SET @subTerms = ???  (Split Term by ' ')

SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE Name LIKE IN (@subTerms)
```

The term I have provided should pull all of the records available in the database.

Comment: string function are different on each rdbms, which one is yours?

Comment: just use `OR` in your SQL

Comment: which way you're connecting db?

Comment: @Mitklantekutli what does this question have to do with a DB Connection..???

Comment: I suppose not even your C#-code will return any results as none of the items in `subterms` matches any of your `items` completely.

Comment: Your current code will give you no matches because `subTerms` will contain "My" and "Product" and none of the strings in `items` exactly matches either of those.  Are you sure you didn't want to do a substring search on the `items` against the values in `subTerms` like `where subTerms.Any(st => i.Contains(st))`?

Comment: @juharr you mean `where subTerms.Any(st => i.Contains(st)).ToList();` but I agree with you as well

Comment: @MethodMan Why would that need a `ToList`?  `Any` returns a `bool`.

Comment: @juharr here is what I am talking about based on the OP's example. also I think that he want's to query on values that are found in the split string array 
`string term = "My Product";
            string[] subTerms = term.Split(' ');
            List<string> items = new List<string>() { "MyProduct", "My Stuff", "Super Product" };
             var matches = (from i in items
                       where subTerms.Any(st => i.Contains(st))
                            select i).ToList();`

Comment: @juharr `Any returns bool` but he's doing a `Select` there for IEnumerable  for from the Select would need to retrun as `ToList() or ToArray()...etc`

Comment: @MethodMan, the first version of this question was drastically different http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33738515/revisions

Comment: Hi guys you are all correct, I messed up the searching portion of the C# version, I've tried to explain without the C# to help you better understand what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @MethodMan I know, I tried to use C# (which I'm usually better at) to explain my point, to an epic fail.

Comment: I think you should do a simple google search on `LIKE` Clause in Sql and how to use wild cards `% %` not sure why you need to split

Comment: so what does your actual SQL look like @Smithy...? you can't use `LIKE IN` that's not proper syntax can you explain how the data will be passed to the query from C# how will the end user(s) determine what product(s) are being queried from..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to say exactly, based on what you've written, but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Name in ('MyProduct', 'My Stuff', 'Super Product')
```

By the way, I've found it LINQPad to be very useful in situations like this: you can point it at a database, write a LINQ query, and then click the "SQL" tab to see what SQL was produced for that query. The SQL tends to be overly verbose, but you can usually get a pretty good idea of what it's doing and come up with a simplified version yourself.

#### Update

Based on the updated question, it's more clear what you want to do. I would recommend that you create a full-text search capable field, and use [`FREETEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) to query it. This is exactly the sort of thing that full-text search was made for.

> Any text, including words, phrases or sentences, can be entered. Matches are generated if any term or the forms of any term is found in the full-text index.

Comment: Where did you get the `Name` property from?

Comment: @DavidKemp: There was so little information in the question that I just had to guess at what he's going for. See the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: If there isn't enough information in a question that you have to make guesses then shouldn't you use the comments to get clarification rather than make assumptions and put them into an answer?

Comment: I think the poorly written question is in my error to be fair, props to @StriplingWarrior for the awesome extrapolation of my question, he's spot on but it's missing the String.Split portion of my question which is where the real meat of the question lies :)

Comment: @Smithy why would you need the Split when you can use `Wild Card % %` with the `LIKE` clause..

Comment: @MethodMan Presumably because the OP wants `Name` to be "My" or "Product" and the `@term` is dynamic and needs to be split to get the terms to compare to.

Comment: Exactly, I've updated my Question again to better reflect what I'm trying to acheive

Comment: @Smithy: See my update. It may not technically answer your question, because free text search behaves differently than LIKE, but it's probably a better solution for the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Having used EntityFramework for the last few years I've lost any and all SQL skills I had and never knew about freetext. Freetext search is exactly what I need, so thank you :)